# Is this a safe way to design a program?

Tags: c++, class

```
class grandfather
{
  protected:
  int test;
};

class father : grandfather
{
  protected:
  int foo;
};

class child : father
{
  public:
  void stuff();
};

void child::stuff()
{
  test = 5;
  while(test == 5)
  {
    foo++;
  }
}

int main(void)
{
  child childObj;

  childObj.stuff();

  return 0;
}
```

I'm just curious if this is a safe way to design a program. A friend of mine stated that initializing child in father or grandfather, or father in grandfather will cause an overflow of some sort.

Anyone wanna give their two cents?

**Not including the while loop!**

Comment: What? The code you posted is perfectly fine except for the UB in `foo++`. (Also you have an infinite loop but I'm sure you knew that already)

Comment: Lemmons: this isn't much of a question.  The code does something completely useless, and (apart from the undefined behaviour) there's not much practically wrong with it.  But, you ask if the design is ok.  Design must relate to purpose, and there is no purpose.  Worse, you're derivation and names imply that all children are necessarily fathers, which in turn requires that they be grandchildren.  In a real-world sense, that's nonsense and doesn't suggest meaningful design.

Comment: *"initializing child in father or grandfather, or father in grandfather"* Where do you do this?

Comment: I should express that this is indeed an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with this (I mean, excepting your `while` loop).

You have a class, with a parent class, which itself has a parent class. No issue.

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted is perfectly fine and your friend is wrong.
If it is a good design cannot be commented until you tell us the *requirement*, other than that semantically the code is correct.

Answer (score 0):

That seems like a totally fine use of inheritance to me.  I don't know why your friend would object to it.